# How to mount a SD card to use with STEAM to expand storage for games

Tags: partitioning, mount, steam, chromebook

NOTE: DO NOT Mark this as a duplicate I know the same question has been asked but my problem has still not been resolved

I have installed Linux(Ubuntu 14.04 with xfce) on a Chromebook using crouton. I am trying to expand my steam Library. 
I have tried everything I can think of. trying Adding entry's to /etc/fstab (this worked) and /etc/mtab (mtab is write protected for some reason)and mounting in /media and making another folder to mount in (/Storage). I Just get  file system must be mounted with execute permissions error and I can not fix this. I can format the drive anyway to get it to work

The drive is /dev/mmcblk1p1 I do not know if it has to be a /dev/sda volume to work I can switch out the drive.

Thanks

Comment: If this question is actually about the issues with accessing the SD card itself, and related errors, and not about how to point Steam at the card, please reword your title and question a bit to better reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out on my own after a lot of wasted time.

1. what file system is the Device
2. what is the device id (run `sudo blkid`) such as `/dev/sda` for a ssd or flash drive or `/dev/mmcblk` for SD cards.

   after that use the id you recieved from `sudo blkid` and (thelast one at the bottom. )
3. Figure out where you want to mount the drive (I will be using `/Storage`)
4. edit `/etc/rc.local` with the proper syntax `/etc/rc.local` is a script that runs on boot.

   Mine looks like this

```sh
     #!/bin/sh -e
     #
     #rc.local 
     #
     # This script is executed at the end of each multiuser run level 
     #Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other  
     #value on error.
     #
     #In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
     #bits.
     #
     #By default this script does nothing.

     sudo mount -t vfat -o rw,noexec /dev/mmcblk1p1 /Storage

     sudo mount -o remount,exec /Storage

     sudo chown sam /Storage

     exit 0
```

ok now let me explain

- you need to mount the drive with `-t` (file system type) 
  (If the file system is fat32 or fat16 use `vfat`, if the drive is exfat use `exfat`, same goes for ntfs(`ntfs` must be lower case),`ext2`,`ext3`,`ext4`)
- Then you need to add paramters `-o rw,noexec` 
  `rw` for `read/write` 
  `noexec` for `don't  execute` we wil add this later
- after that use the id you recieved from `sudo blkid` and (the last one at the bottom.) `/dev/sda` or `/dev/mmcblk`
- then use a folder you have premade
- next remount the folder with execute permissions ( and yes you have to remount this or it will not work)

  ```
  sudo mount -o t,remount,exec /your/mount/dir
  ```
- Finally take ownership of the folder so steam can use it

  ```
  sudo chown <your username> /your/mount/dir
  ```

Sorry if this was confusing I tried to put a lot of information in this if you have questions I will be watching the comments on this

Answer (score 1):

You should mount it using umask and dmask in /etc/fstab. For example:

```
/dev/sda    /media/additional_drive_target_dir  ntfs-3g defaults,auto,fmask=0077,dmask=0022,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000   0 1
```